# how can I make thread in TCP server multi client dialogue

Tags: c#, networking, tcp, client

**I am working on multi thread server and clients written in C#.So Guide
 me how can I make multi thread in server for multi client.**

---

This is my Server Code

```
class Program
            {
                static byte[] Buffer
                {

                    get; 
                    set; 
                }
                static void Main(string[] args)
                {
                    Program obj = new Program();
                    Console.WriteLine("Server");
                    obj.server_reciver();


                }
              static Socket sck;

                public void server_reciver()
                {
                    try
                    {
                        sck = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
                        IPEndPoint localEndPoint;
                        localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.2"), 1);
                        sck.Bind(localEndPoint);

                        sck.Listen(100);
                        while (true)
                        {
                            Socket accepted = sck.Accept();
                            // Buffer = new byte[accepted.ReceiveBufferSize];
                            Buffer = new byte[accepted.SendBufferSize];
                            int bytesRead = accepted.Receive(Buffer);

                            byte[] formatted = new byte[bytesRead];

                            //for (int i = 0; i < bytesRead; i++)
                            for (int i = 0; i < bytesRead; i++)
                            {
                                formatted[i] = Buffer[i];
                                //Console.WriteLine(Buffer[i] + "\r\n");
                            }
                            //string strData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Buffer);
                            string strData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(formatted);
                            Console.Write("From Client=>" + strData + "\n");
                            Console.WriteLine("Enter the text:");
                            string data = Console.ReadLine();
                            byte[] reply = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
                            accepted.Send(reply);
                            //accepted.Close();
                            accepted.Close();
                        }


                        sck.Close();
                        Console.Read();

                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                        {

                        }
                }

            }
```

---

This is my Client side and I make more then one client here is one

```
class Program
                {
                    static byte[] Buffer
                    {

                        get;
                        set;
                    }

                    static Socket sck;
                    static void Main(string[] args)
                    {

                        Program obj = new Program();
                        obj.client_send();
                    }

                    public void client_send()
                    {
                        while (true)
                        {
                            sck = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);


                            IPEndPoint localEndPoint;
                            localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("182.188.247.244"), 1);
                            //localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.45"), 1);
                            try
                            {
                                sck.Connect(localEndPoint);

                            }
                            catch
                            {
                                Console.Write("Unable to connect to remote end point!\r\n");
                                //Main(args);
                            }

                            try
                            {
                                Console.Write("Enter Text: ");
                                string text = Console.ReadLine();
                                byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text);
                                sck.Send(data);

                                Buffer = new byte[sck.SendBufferSize];
                                int bytesRead = sck.Receive(Buffer);

                                byte[] formatted = new byte[bytesRead];


                                for (int i = 0; i < bytesRead; i++)
                                {
                                    formatted[i] = Buffer[i];
                                    //Console.WriteLine(Buffer[i] + "\r\n");
                                }
                                string strData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(formatted);
                                Console.Write("From Server=>" + strData + "\n");

                                sck.Close();
                            }
                            catch(Exception )
                            {

                            }
                        }

                        Console.ReadLine();
                    }
                }
```

Comment: localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.2"), 1);

Comment: LocelEndPoint ip is 127.0.0.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, you would keep `Socket accepted = sck.Accept();` on the main thread, but once a request is received you would pass it to another thread for servicing.  This allows the main thread to listed to another incoming request.  You can use `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` to move the work to a background thread.  Note that making it multi-threaded is going to give you problems since the response is read from Console.  How is each worker thread to know that it gets the right data?  But I assume you'll replace that with real server logic.

At some point, you may find that this doesn't scale.  You're using blocking IO calls (`Send` and `Receive`) so your threads will spend a lot of time waiting.  Non-blocking IO would be ideal, but it is more complicated to write.